# what are the units for "Average Network In" for aws ec2 autoscaling groups

Tags: amazon-web-services

When configuring scaling for an ec2 autoscaling group, I have the option of scaling on ASGAverageNetworkIn which is defined as the average number of bytes received in five minutes....

Averaged how?

In other words: if I wanted to maintain something near 50% use of a 10Gigabit connection, would that be 625000 or 187500000 average bytes?

It's looking like it's probably 187500000 average bytes, but I can't find any documentation to definitively confirm this. (If it said "total bytes received in 5 minutes by one ec2 instance", for example, that would definitively confirm this.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to calculate figures to use for the CloudWatch Alarm, I would recommend you **look at historical information** on the metric.

Identify periods where the server was "too busy" and you would have liked to scale-out, then check what the Network metric was showing in CloudWatch. This way, you can map "real world" situations back to the metric values, which will more reliably work in future.

In fact, look at all the metrics (CPU, Network, etc) to see which metrics can reliably identify **when a scaling event should have occurred**. This will be much more reliable that trying to calculate a value that *might* be an indication of load.

Comment: Not much help when rolling out a new service. But,  yeah, that apparently is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's the average of total bytes received by 1 EC2 instance across either 1 or 5min, depending on if you're using enhance monitoring (1min) or not (5min).

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-scaling-target-tracking.html :

```
ASGAverageNetworkIn—Average number of bytes received by a single instance on all network interfaces.

ASGAverageNetworkOut—Average number of bytes sent out from a single instance on all network interfaces.
```

Comment: Hmm... so a rolling average? That sounds plausible. (Unfortunately, I'm not currently working with aws intances, so I'm not in a position to try verifying this answer. But it sounds correct, so I'm going to at least vote for it.)